# Attribute is missing : Android namespace prefix

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="#F0FFFFFF"/>
 <stroke android:width="1dp" color="#A00080FF"/>
 <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="0dp"
  android:right="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `android:color`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#F0FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#A00080FF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: <FrameLayout android:id="@id/action_bar_activity_content"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_action_bar"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="top">

Comment: it's error "Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: If you have another question please ask it separately. And include full xml if you think there are multiple errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#F0FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        color="#A00080FF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="56dip"
            android:layout_height="36dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="12dip"
            android:paddingRight="12dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

Comment: it's error "Duplicate id @+id/image, already defined earlier in this layout"

Answer (score 0):

Add This Line at first line and add `android:` before color attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Your code should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#F0FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#A00080FF"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: <FrameLayout android:id="@id/action_bar_activity_content"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_action_bar"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="top">

Comment: it's error "Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children 
 where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: what you are asking exactly?

Comment: that is the other error

Comment: @JuliarNasution if this answer is useful to you please accept it